# traverse.clearCache is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

in https://babeljs.io/ when i want to compile my ES6 code, this error will be shown:

```
traverse.clearCache is not a function
```

My code is a simple code like:
let i = 1;

```
console.log(i)
```

Comment: Clear the browser cache, or open in incognito window. I could make it work without any problem: https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DYUwLgBAlhC8EAYBQBjA9gOwM5tAOmDQHMAKKASiA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.3.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can untick Minify in the left.it will work.